# Can I convince Ruby's MongoDB driver to return hashes rather than BSON documents?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, hash

I am in a position where I need to fetch documents from a Mongo database and serialize them to YAML. This results in a lot of this: `!ruby/hash:BSON::Document`.

I have read docs and Googled to no avail. The only solution I can see is to recursively walk the result document and run `Hash[doc]` on every hash encountered. This seems like it should be unnecessary though.

Can I convince Ruby's MongoDB driver to return hashes rather than BSON documents?